# roxterm emulator: Change Profile in all Active TTYs

Tags: terminal-emulator

The terminal emulator roxterm saves an environment variable containing an unique id for each tty session.

e.g:

```
echo $ROXTERM_ID
0x26d39e0
```

This is needed in order to send dbus messages to roxterm, which will take effect only for this particular tty.

According to the manual settings of the current tty can be changed like so:

```
dbus-send --session /net/sf/roxterm/Options net.sf.roxterm.Options.SetColourScheme string:$ROXTERM_ID string:Tango
```

This changes the color theme to "Tango". It works.

How can I change all currently open roxterm windows in the same way?

According to the manual `dbus-send --session /net/sf/roxterm/Options net.sf.roxterm.Options.OptionsChanged string:Colours string:Tango` should do the trick. However, it has no effect.