# access environment variables of each active tty in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

Is there a way to access all the environment variables of all currently opened TTY's?

Say, a terminal emulator puts an unique id to each TTY window in an environment variable. Could I get a list of all the ids?

Comment: What is your goal? It would be easier to help if I knew the purpose.

Comment: If you are on Linux, look at `/proc/[pid]/environ`.  See `man 7 proc`.  Bear in mind that the environment is tied to a *process*, not a tty.  For example, one terminal can have several shells running, and several background programs with different environments.

Comment: @True Y: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452047/roxterm-emulator-change-profile-in-all-active-ttys for a more detailed description of the particular usecase that lead me to this general question.

Comment: @cdarke Yes, I'm on linux. Updated this. Alright, this is good to be reminded of. so technically the teminal emulator when opening a tty immediately spawns a shell (e.g. a bash process), which holds the environment that also includes its unique id as a variable. So acutally I'd have to search /proc for all bash processes, that have been spawned by the terminal emulator, and then go ahead with this? (could be done via ps.. as well I guess)

Comment: List all bash processes with `ps`, find their PIDs and search `/proc` for them...

Comment: As @Nidhoegger said.  Remember that the tty is part of `ps` output.  Usually it is the login that creates the shell, not the emulator.  However some emulators create a login shell and some a non-login shell (affects which start-up files are called).